# Why is my for loop overwriting my output?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand what I am doing wrong, but not how to fix it.
I am trying to write "Z" to excel and then save once I have looped through all my list entries, but the index in the DF resets every iteration and overwrites so I only see my last list entry and not all 5.

Any help is appreciated.

```
orig_df = (pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx"))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NEW_Frame.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

List1 = ['Market_A', 'Market_B', 'Market_C', 'Market_D', 'Market_E']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Location','Data1','Data2','Data3'], index=range(5))

for i in range(len(List1)) :
        M = List1[i]
        P = List1[i]
        M = abc[abc.Location.str.contains(M)]

        Z = [{'Location': P , 'Data1': abc['Data1'].sum(), 'Data2': abc['Data2'].sum(), 'Data3': 
        abc['Data3'].sum(),}]

        Z = pd.DataFrame(Z)

        Z.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=P)

        i += 1

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

since I don't have your input file I am just saving a small test dataframe, but I had no trouble saving all 5 pages with this:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NEW_Frame.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for sheet_name in ['Market_A', 'Market_B', 'Market_C', 'Market_D', 'Market_E']:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'test1': [1,1,1], 'test2': [2,2,2]})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

writer.save()
```

Could you try this and see if you have any issues?

Answer (score -1):

```
orig_df = (pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx"))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NEW_Frame.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

List1 = ['Market_A', 'Market_B', 'Market_C', 'Market_D', 'Market_E']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Location','Data1','Data2','Data3'], index=range(5))
location, data1, data2, data3 = []

for i in range(len(List1)) :
    M = List1[i]
    P = List1[i]
    M = abc[abc.Location.str.contains(M)]
    location.append(p)
    data1.append(abc['Data1'].sum())
    data2.append(abc['Data2'].sum())
    data3.append(abc['Data3'].sum())
    i += 1
Z = [{'Location': location , 'Data1': data1, 'Data2': data2, 'Data3': 
    data3,}]

Z = pd.DataFrame(Z)

Z.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=P)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Bring  write.save() into for loop by adding indentation.

Comment: Thank you, but if I do that in the loop only my 1 list entry is written and then the xlsx file is closed. Do I need to close and open the file to append for every loop?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood question before. you will have to create all columns data in a list before you create a dictionary and convert it into a DataFrame. Try this

Comment: Thank you. I think I did what you are saying. I created an empty data frame with the column names before the loop and inside the loop I kept appending.